# Unable to bind JSON to angular 4 Object

Tags: angular

I am returning a JSON object but the `*ngFor` loop is not rendering anything.

Component:

```
@Input() users: Observable<IUser>;

this.users = this.getUserByRole(this.role);

 getUserByRole(role) {

        return this._searchService.getUsersByRole(role);
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <tr saSmartMenu *ngFor='let data of users | async' (click)="onEditUser.emit(data)">
                                    <td>{{data.ssn }}</td>
                                    <td>{{data.userName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{data.lastName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{data.ofcSymbId }}</td>
                                    <td>{{data.role }}</td>
                                </tr>
```

search.service:

```
 getUsersByRole(role:string) {
            return this.http.get(this.url+role)
                .map(res => res.json().data);
        }
```

I check the JSON with a restful client and my object is exactly like the JSON I am getting.

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Hey Drew! Maybe stupid question, but just to make sure, your response actually contains `data`-object from which you are trying to extract? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 got it solved, I am learning.

Comment: I see that it's solved, glad to hear :) Happy coding, until we see again :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe in order for your Observable to make the request. From the ***[Documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md#cold-vs-hot-observables)***

> **Cold vs. Hot Observables**
>
> Cold observables start running upon subscription, i.e., the observable
>   sequence only starts pushing values to the observers when Subscribe is
>   called. Values are also not shared among subscribers.

In order to call your service do this

**Component**

```
@Input() users: Observable<IUser>;

 getUserByRole(role) {
  this._searchService.getUsersByRole(role).subscribe(res=> {
         this.users = res;
        });
    }
```

**Service**

```
 getUsersByRole(role:string) {
            return this.http.get(this.url+role)
                .map(res => res.json());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but I believe you need to subscribe to your observable to get a result... Something like this:

```
this.http.get(this.url+role)
    .map(res => res.json().data)
    .subscribe(result => result); // Not sure what you want in your fat arrow function here
```